# Docker не подключается к Mysql (Can't connect to local MySQL)

Tags: docker

Нужна помощь с запуском mariadb через Dockerfile.

После запуска службы `service mysql start` получаю ответ `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")`

Не могу понять в чем дело и почему так происходит

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV TZ=Europe/Kiev

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update && \
 apt-get install -y mariadb-server

RUN service mysql start

RUN sleep 10

RUN mysql -uroot -e "create database zabbix character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;" && mysql -uroot -e "grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost identified by 'testpass'" && mysql -uroot -e "flush privileges;"
```

Вывод получается такой:

```
Step 5/8 : RUN service mysql start
 ---> Running in f24ff36ddb3e
Removing intermediate container f24ff36ddb3e
 ---> d53415b09e85
Step 6/8 : RUN sleep 10
 ---> Running in 4493579346ec
Removing intermediate container 4493579346ec
 ---> 85b1b689d6c5
Step 7/8 : RUN mysql -uroot -e "create database zabbix character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;" && mysql -uroot -e "grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost identified by 'testpass'" && mysql -uroot -e "flush privileges;"
 ---> Running in efacff2e5952
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
The command '/bin/sh -c mysql -uroot -e "create database zabbix character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;" && mysql -uroot -e "grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost identified by 'testpass'" && mysql -uroot -e "flush privileges;"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Создайте контейнер без последнего RUN зайдите в него и посмотрите какая именно конфигурация у mysql, куда он кладет файловый сокет (если вообще это делает). Это может отличаться в разных образах, которые вы берете за основу. Хотя у меня есть некоторые сомнения даже по поводу того, что service start можно использовать при сборке образа, это нарушает идеологию docker. особенно настораживает, что между командами run удаляется промежуточный образ. по факту контенера в котором выполнялся service уже не существует на момент команд mysql

Comment: Да, думаю мои подозрения про нарушение идеологии верны... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673357/creating-a-default-database-in-mysql-using-dockerfile

Comment: @Mike Хм. А как тогда в данном случае будет правильно запустить сервер и создать ему БД для дальнейших манипуляций?

Comment: ну вот по той ссылке в принципе написано. там на сколько я понял предлагают дописать нужные инструкции в файл, который в образе создает пользователя. Но конечно надо посмотреть используемый вами за основу образ есть ли там такой файл, который выполняется при создании БД

Answer (score 1):

Во время билда нового образа никакого контейнера и процессов в нем не существует. запуск БД mysql происходит во время билда, но процесс тут же завершается. И базы данных во время билда еще нет, так что производить изменения не где.

В основной ветке [билдов mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) база данных создается при первом запуске контейнера на основе образа. При этом скрипт entry point выполняет любые файлы из каталога /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d образа. Вам надо создать файл с расширением .sql с нужными командами для инициализации БД, разместить его рядом с Dockerfile, в который включить команду COPY для размещения этого файла в папке /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d образа.